# Rails 3 global and optional route for format to assist page caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, routes, format

I would like to page cache just about everything in my API, so instead of the `.format` or `?format=` way that is usually called, I want to make the final url param hardcoded into the route. Examples:

```
/sounds/123/xml
/sounds/123/json
/sounds/123/whats_new/xml
/sounds/xml
/sounds/blah_method/xml
```

I know I can use named and matched routes to add this to EVERY call, but that is not very `DRY` and seems like there should be a better rails way. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the route recognition or generation with the [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) plugin. It is very flexible, take a look.

For the generation, your use case would be to check if there's a `params[:format]` and in that case add a new segment at the end of the url.

If you also need recognition, this time it's the opposite, check if there's a trailing segment with either `'/xml'` or `'/json'`and in that case add `params[:format]`to match it.